# Add-in can't run in Office Professional Plus 2016

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

One of my add-ins, [Formula Formatter](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380385?tab=Overview), works well in Office 365. However, one client told me it cannot be loaded in `Office Professional Plus 2016`.

Does anyone know what may be the reason? Should we do something special in the manifest xml for `Office Professional Plus 2016`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its manifest, Formula Formatter specifies the requirement set ExcelAPI with a minimum version of 1.2.  Per the documentation for that requirement set (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets) your customer will need to be running "Version 1601 (Build 6741.2088) or later". Customers that have a non-subscription version of Office won't have that requirement set.

If you remove the requirement set from the manifest, your add-in would be available on Office 2016 but you would need to ensure that your add-in has a good user experience when they are not present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I have several questions: 1) where did you see my `manifest.xml`? 2) `Customers that have a non-subscription version of Office won't have that requirement set.` ==> it seems that `Professional Plus 2016` is a non-subscription version, but it must have a version number, right? Are you saying that its version number must be less than `1601`?

Comment: 1 - I used fiddler to view it while it was downloading to my office client.

Comment: 2 - The documentation page states that the version number for Pro Plus 2016 is Office 2016 installed via MSI is 16.0.4266.1001 which I believe is 1509 or lower. I wouldn't expect these APIs to be in the MSI version.  FWIW, we're having some good discussions about how to clarify our versioning story as it's too complicated right now.

Comment: I have some other questions: 3) if I remove totally the block of `<Requirements>`, does it mean users of Excel 2013 can see my add-in in their store? 4) If I modify the manifest xml and update the add-in, will it be re-validated by Office Store? I ask this question, because last time it took several weeks to validate an add-in...

Comment: 3 - Removing the <Requirements> section will unblock your add-in from being available on Excel 2013.  The best way to understand where its going to be loaded is to use the same tool as we use for validation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-validator) That said, you may end up in a situation where your add-in has a runtime failure because the APIs aren't available.

Comment: 4 - Yes, you'll need to submit to the Office store and it will be re-validated especially considering that it will be available on different versions of Excel than the previous version. I do apologize for the delay.

Comment: Another question is: 5) when the new manifest.xml and the newly changed add-in is being reviewed, what will happen to the existing version? Will the existing version keep working?

Comment: When you submit an update to your add-in, the existing version reamins available while the update is being validated.